# Cannot align button properly below text in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to align a button below text in the left side in react native. Below is my code:

```
function Description(props){
    return(
        <><View style={{flexShrink: 1}}><Text style={{flexShrink: 1}}>{props.description}</Text></View>
        <View><Button title="Delete" /></View></>
    );
}
```

But this is how it is appearing:
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug1qF.png)

I want the blue colored delete button to be below the text and on the left side. I have tried to put Text in the View as well and give flexDirection to be column, but that isn't working as well. Please tell me the change that I need to make in my code to place the button properly.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out...

```
<View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
    <Text>{props.description}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        marginTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: "cornflowerblue",
        height: 45,
        width: 100,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "white" }}>Delete</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Edit as per your requirement ...

Comment: alignItems: "center",  justifyContent: "center", this both are placing Delete txt in center...
alignSelf:'center' in TouchableOpacity style, if you want the button to be in center